# Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" while scanning barcode using zxing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zxing

I'm facing an issue related to scanning the barcodes using the android device while using library Zxing.
I'm getting this error on some specific devices **(MI Note 7 Pro and Note 8 Pro)** for other devices its working perfectly fine.

**Library Version:** 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8' from app file

**Exception from my console window :** E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

Before posting this question to SO I've already checked all other links related to this problem but nothing works for me.

Site from where I've created barcodes https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/qr/
Please help!

Comment: What else does the LogCat say?

Comment: So basically i have included a zxing library for scanning barcodes in my project. But the thing is whenever i run my application on mi device , then logcat keep giving error Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist".  And when i use my application on other devices api lower than 25 , it works fine. But on devices api greater than 25 , it gives camera error.

Comment: I/Camera: handleMessage: 16
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"